# Why is my internet connection lost when I pick up the phone?

Tags: internet

During the last month, every time I pick up the phone, the Internet Connection is lost. This didn't happen for many years.

My modem is wired to my PC. I don't use wireless, and I have turned the wireless mode off.

I have a new DSL filter

Why does it happen now?

Comment: Have you contacted your provider?

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing your DSL filter.

Comment: I use a brand new one. I bought this one after I started having the problem

Comment: Even with filters, if there are issues on the line, you can see symptoms like this. Has it been raining more heavily in your area recently? Check the NID and the box on the street and make sure there aren't water issues (bad seals, open doors). Other things that can cause issues are shorts on the line, you'll have to get your ISP to run an MTR to get more detailed information about the line status.